# PHP switch returning inconsistent results

Tags: php

I have the following switch statement, which should be returning an array of messages sent to/from a user:

```
<?php
// Load libs, verify user
require_once '../bootstrap.php';

switch ($_GET['folder']) {
  case 'inbox':
    $messages = Message::sentToUser($userId);
    break;

  case 'sent':
    $messages = Message::sentByUser($userId);
    break;

  default:
    $messages = Message::sentToUser($userId);
    break;
}

$json = json_encode($messages);
echo $json;
```

Messages.php

```
  public static function sentToUser($user_id)
  {
    $messages = DB::table('messages')
                  ->order_by('id', 'DESC')
                  ->where('sent_to_id', '=', $user_id)
                  ->where('show_to_receiver', '=', 1)
                  ->get();

    return ($messages) ? $messages : array();
  }
```

Everything works fine if I pass in a `folder` param:

```
[
  {
    id: "1"
    title: "Test Message"
    message: ""
    read: "0"
    date_sent: "2014-05-14 15:08:43"
    date_read: null
    sent_from_id: "5"
    sent_to_id: "40"
  }
]
```

However, in the default case (no folder param given), PHP throws `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: folder` (expected), and `$messages` is returned as an object, not array:

```
{
  id: "1"
  title: "Test Message"
  message: ""
  read: "0"
  date_sent: "2014-05-14 15:08:43"
  date_read: null
  sent_from_id: "5"
  sent_to_id: "40"
}
```

I would have expected `$messages` to be set to the same thing if `$_GET['folder']` is `'inbox'` or `undefined`. Any ideas as to the root of the inconsistency?

Comment: And you should never, ever, access request parameters directly!

Comment: could you show the function, and perhaps a 'var_dump()` of the correct and incorrect results. It is very odd that a notice would change the return type

Comment: you state that it is "unexpected" or "inconsistent" can you show the different results that lead you to think it's inconsistent? It seems to me that it will either give you one of the switch cases or return an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$folder = isset($_GET['folder']) ? $_GET['folder'] : '';
switch ($folder) {
...
```

Comment: While this does make it work, I'm mostly interested in why it's returning something, but just not wrapping it in the array as expected. I would have expected the switch to either error out or return the same thing.

Comment: @JonathanBender me too, please edit your question as per my earlier comment, im intrigued.

Comment: @JonathanBender Perhaps $messages is already initialized and an object BEFORE the above code, so the entire switch block does not run (due to error) and you see the old value?

Comment: Even though the missing variable is bad, to PHP it's just a `NOTICE`, not an `ERROR`.  If a variable doesn't exist, the value is replaced with `NULL`.  [Here's an example](http://ideone.com/uNjUs5).
In OP's case, `switch(NULL)` is syntactically valid and will run the `default` case.

Comment: @GigaWatt correct, i just tested and got the same result. Clearly something odd is going on with the OPs code or setup

Comment: Updated the question to show what is returned from the function, as well as the complete contents of the file.

Comment: @JonathanBender can you show the `sentToUser($userId);` function, this is bizzare

Comment: Updated to include that

Comment: @JonathanBender Well this is strange, laravels `fluent->get()` should always return an array (an empty one if no results), so i just cant see how this could happen. Since you accepted my answer, did you find out the cause?

Comment: Agreed about the strangeness, hence the post. I was hoping someone else might have run into something similar and could give a quick explanation. I was not able to find the root of it, no, but decided to go with a "well this works, so we'll go with it" approach and just implemented your fix.

Comment: Re: why this works. For some reason (I don't know why this is), form elements that rely on an attribute for their value do not get passed from client to server when a form is submitted. For example, a checkbox with the name "mycheckbox" and the attribute 'checked="checked"' will show up in the `$_GET` array as `$_GET["mycheckbox"]`; uncheck that checkbox and submit the form and  `$_GET["mycheckbox"]` will not be set. In your case, I'm guessing you're using a select element - if none of the options has a `selected` attribute, it won't show up in `$_GET`.

Comment: Fair enough, `productivity > curiosity` i hate weird bugs like this. @Kryten the odd part is the return value change (array of objects vs object), not the notice.

Comment: Actually FWIW this is an API endpoint so everything is being passed as a URL param.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if it's a bug or by design, but it always seemed like weird behaviour to me.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `$_GET['folder']` is not defined, so you better use `isset()` to check it.
***P.S. :*** you should always validate user's input (like `$_GET` and `$_POST`)

Comment: I recognize that it isn't defined, but isn't `default` intended to catch that sort of thing? The function is also not 'blowing up', it's just returning something different than expected.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't have a value assigned to it, it's actually not defined as a variable.

Comment: @Jonathan Bender : As `$_GET['folder']` is not defined it throws an error, that there is no such variable.It is not the `switch` bug or feature but php, as no matter where you put your variable : in `function` call, `if` or wherever, if the variable is not defined, it will throw this error.And `default` is for unrecognized is `case`s values, not for undefined variables.

Comment: @JonathanBender -- the error breaks the functionality of the switch, so it shouldn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking whether they are requesting a valid folder or not, which might become important. It's better if you do something along the lines of what @user574632 suggested, but I'd add some more code. Why would `$_GET['folder']` be empty? Why would it be a different value? You should account for these **two different** cases. If the folder can be empty and it means inbox, then say so in your code. This becomes more appropriate then:

```
// Acknowledge only for the empty folder if it follows your logic, not for everything
$folder = isset($_GET['folder']) ? $_GET['folder'] : 'inbox';

switch ($folder) {
  case 'inbox':
    $messages = Message::sentToUser($userId);
    break;

  case 'sent':
    $messages = Message::sentByUser($userId);
    break;

  // Other code would cause an exception, error, exit or whatever. LOG THAT.
  default:
    throw new InvalidFolderException("User trying to access an invalid folder");
    break;
}
```

Comment: You are creating `$folder` but not using it.

Comment: Sorry, small mistake (;